# Sum and number of divisors

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If the sum of divisors is prime, how can I show that the number of divisors is also prime?
I've tried to use definitons, but I'm not getting anything.

Comment: Do you mean that "if $\sigma(n)$, the sum of all divisors of $n$, is prime, then $d(n)$, the number of divisors of $n$, is prime"?

Comment: Do you have any examples of numbers $n$ such that $\sigma(n)$ is prime? I can think of only one such $n.$

Comment: @WillJagy think Mersenne!

Comment: Clearly the numbers with an odd no. of divisors are perfect squares. So we have to show if the sum of the divisors of a perfect square are prime then the no. of divisors is also prime.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown good, found first few 2 =  2    sigma  3   d  2
 /// 4 =  2^2    sigma  7   d  3
 /// 9 =  3^2    sigma  13   d  3
 /// 16 =  2^4    sigma  31   d  5
 /// 25 =  5^2    sigma  31   d  3
 /// 64 =  2^6    sigma  127   d  7
 /// 289 =  17^2    sigma  307   d  3
 /// 729 =  3^6    sigma  1093   d  7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sum of the divisiors of the number $$N=p_1^{a_1}\cdots p_n^{a_n}$$ is $$(1+p_1+\cdots +p_1^{a_1})\cdots (1+p_n+\cdots +p_n^{a_n})$$ All the factors are greater than $1$, so if $N$ has more than one prime factor, the sum of the divisors cannot be prime. Hence we can concentrate on the prime powers. For a prime power $p^n$ , the sum of divisors is $$\frac{p^{n+1}-1}{p-1}$$ and the number of divisors is $n+1$. If $n+1$ is composite, let us say $n+1=ab$ with $a,b>1$ , then $p^a-1\mid p^{n+1}-1$ giving the non-trivial factor $\frac{p^a-1}{p-1}$. This completes the proof of the statement.